# run python2 within python3 script and the same process

Tags: python, subprocess

while using suprprocess to run python2 script in python3, I noticed that if I print os.getpid() in this subprocess, it has a different pid than the parent process that made it, which was not surprising.

However, is there a way to execute this python2 script in python3 and while having both owned by the same process?
I would also appreciate if you could mention other ways for executing python2 script in python3.

Comment: Are you asking how to run two python scripts in separate threads of the same process? You could probably do this with the [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) module, but I don't see why it would be useful. They won't execute in parallel because of the CPython [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).

Comment: @EmersonHarkin but with threading we won't be able to execute python2 script in python3 right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What are you trying to do? Are you trying to `import` the contents of a python2 file into a python3 script?

Comment: @EmersonHarkin so I have a script that if I run it with python3, it gives the 'dynamic module does not define...' error. but I need this script running so that another script of mine can work within python3. So far when I did it with subprocess, it didn't work which I imagine should be because they are now in separate process and my python3 script doesn't see it (both the python3 and the python2 scripts that I have are wrappers of come c++ scripts.

Comment: I'm trying to do what described here: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/Using%20a%20C%2B%2B%20class%20in%20Python regarding 'class with nodehandle'. but the available solution that they give is only in python2